# PHP+MySQL is too slow on one machine

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried all the suggestions I could find from similar questions, none of them seem to help.

I'm running a PHP script to add some data into the database - only around 1K lines. Here is the full code I'm using:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$t_start = microtime(true);
require('../php/connect.php');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('base/en/stringlist.js'));
foreach ($data as $cat => $values) {
  $category = mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
  foreach ($values as $key => $info) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    $text = mysql_real_escape_string($info->text);
    $tip = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($info->tip) ? $info->tip : '');
    $query = "INSERT INTO locale_strings (name,text,tip,category) VALUES ('$name','$text','$tip','$category')";
    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
      echo mysql_error() . "\n";
    }
  }
}
echo 'Time: ' . round(microtime(true) - $t_start, 4) . ' seconds.';
?>
```

(I apologize for the `mysql_` syntax). I have used this on 3 PCs, all running Win7/8 with a fairly recent XAMPP installation. On two of the machines, this script takes about 2-3 seconds to execute, while on one the third one it times out after 30 seconds (after adding ~900 lines). What could cause it to run 10x slower?

If I comment out the `mysql_query` line, it takes 0.012 seconds to run, so the code itself isn't the problem. The database is on localhost, and it is included in the `etc/hosts` file - same as on the other machines.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locale_strings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `locked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tip` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4833 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `locale_strings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `locale_strings`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4833;
```

Comment: If you have sql queries running slow they can be because of alot of reasons. First is obviously the hardware limitation. Even after that you need to craft proper queries and at the same time optimize database architecture to make queries faster.

Comment: Seems to be a hardware or some other limitation on the third machine.

Comment: Well yeah I know the question is too specific, I'm basically asking if there are any known specific hardware issues that could cause this.

Comment: If you open a task manager or something on the slow computer while it’s running the queries, is it CPU bound? If it is, what’s taking up all the processor time? If it’s not CPU bound, it’ll be a bit harder to pinpoint the problem…

Comment: No, I literally just started up the machine, CPU isn't clogged up at all, otherwise I wouldn't ask the question :(

Comment: You're using InnoDB. InnoDB is an ACID compliant engine. Each query runs in autocommit mode. That means that each query **forces** the HDD to write down a record (instead of letting the OS schedule it). Your HDD, if mechanical, has about 300 I/O per second. That means that for about 900-1000 records it can take 2-3 seconds to write them down. There are many ways to optimize this. One way is to use PDO, prepare the statement, start transaction and commit it after 1000 inserts have been done. You should see the execution go down to below 50 milliseconds.

Comment: @N.B. wow thanks now it takes 0.1 seconds with MyISAM... I'm pretty sure I used InnoDB on some of the other machines, though >.>

Comment: Using InnoDB is ok, you just need to bear in mind to group stuff in a transaction to make it insert fast on mechanical disks. Using MyISAM, as I mentioned, lets the OS schedule the write. The records aren't really there, they're buffered so you can lose them.

Comment: Well yes, its not production code, so I didn't bother with any of that, but I still found it suspicious. I actually think the other two machines run MyISAM, and I set this one to InnoDB because my web server has it as the default, but I suppose their hardware is very different from mine so it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: @N.B. I upvoted your comment but it would be better if you copied your
useful answer into an actual answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan - thanks, I wrote an answer with the example code, hopefully it will work (didn't test it though) :)

Answer (score 3):

The InnoDB storage engine is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant. Each query runs in autocommit mode and will use input output operation of the disk, which is quite expensive. That means that every query forces the hard disk drive (HDD) to write a record (instead of letting the OS schedule it). Your HDD, if mechanical, has about 300 I/O per second. That means that for about 900-1000 records it can take 2-3 seconds to write them down.

By contrast, using the MyISAM storage engine, as I mentioned, lets the OS schedule the write. The records aren’t immediately written to disk; they’re [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) in memory before being saved to disk. While this means MyISAM is faster, the trade-off is the risk of data loss (if the system were to crash or lose power while there was data in the buffer which hadn’t yet been written to disk).

To optimize this, the usual way is to wrap several inserts into a single transaction. One way is to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), prepare the statement, start transaction and commit it after 1000 inserts have been done.
That allows the hard drive to write down a lot of data in one operation.

Your code rewritten using PDO would flow similar to this (note - didn't test, don't copy paste, it's just for reference):

```
// connect.php - note that the code around PDO should go in the file connect.php as per example
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//===================================================================
// The rest of the code
//===================================================================

// Decode JSON
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('base/en/stringlist.js'));

// Check if there were any errors decoding JSON
if(empty($data))
{
    echo "Something went wrong, error: " . json_last_error_msg();
    exit;
}

try
{
    // Prepare the statement - it's prepared once, used multiple times
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO locale_strings (name, text, tip, category) VALUES (:name, :text, :tip, :category)");

    // Start the transaction

    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    // Loop through the data, bind parameters, execute and when done - commit
    foreach ($data as $cat => $values)
    {
        foreach ($values as $key => $info)
        {
            $stmt->bindValue(':name', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':text', $info->text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':tip', isset($info->tip) ? $info->tip : '', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(':category', $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }

    // And finally, tell the HDD to write down the info.
    // Note - for this example, we issued all the contents in a single commit.
    // That might not be the sweet spot so you can optimize later on with checking
    // how many records are optimal go do down to the disk in a single I/O
    $pdo->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    if($pdo->inTransaction())
    {
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }

    // I assume you know how to handle exceptions, messages, trace etc.
}
```